# drop down menu expand down

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make this form.

thing

---

thing

.

if click the thing,

.

thing

- thing 1
- thing 2

---

thing

.

like this.

But I can find only menu expand left or right.
how can I implement the menu for expand down?

Comment: Maybe this [Tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/9942/android-expandablelistview-example-tutorial) will help you.

Comment: You should search for [Accordion View](https://github.com/SysdataSpA/FancyAccordionView)

Comment: you need to look at ExpandableListView, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the many ways you can achieve your objective

Step 1: Put the below dependency in your app gradle file.

```
    implementation 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.4.2@aar'
```

Step 2: Your layout can be designed like below:

```
     <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/card_id"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            app:cardElevation="4dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"                  
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"                  
                    android:text="Thing"
                    android:textAlignment="viewStart"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/expandableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:ael_duration="400"          
        app:ael_expanded="false"
        app:ael_interpolator="fastOutSlowIn"
        app:ael_orientation="vertical"
        android:elevation="4dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="none"            
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                android:text="Thing 1" />

                <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="none"            
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                android:text="Thing 2" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout>
```

Step 3:

Declare the Views.

```
    CardView cardView;
    ExpandableRelativeLayout expandableLayout;
```

Bind the views and register onClickListener on CardView in onCreate() method

```
     cardView = findViewById(R.id.card_id);
     expandableLayout = findViewById(R.id.expandableLayout1);

     cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            expandableLayout.toggle(); // toggle expand and collapse
        }
    });
```